# Hide field based on drop down selection in sharepoint new item

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010, show-hide

I am new to sharepoint.

I have created a list. In the new item window, i would like display or hide fields based on drop down selection value. I know it can be done using jquery as it is shown in below link. but i dont know where to place the code.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88064/hide-show-field-on-list-form-based-on-value-from-another-field

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your list main page then

```
List Tools>List>Form Web Parts>Default New Form
```

Then click on `Add a Web Part` and under `Categories` select `Media and Content > Content Editor`. Click `Add` to add it to the page.
On the left side of the Content Editor, you will see an arrow. Click on it and choose `Edit Web Part`. Under `Content Link` click on the button to open the `Text Editor`. Add the URL of your aspx page.
For instance if the page is stored in the `Site Assets` library and is called `newform.aspx` the url is `[url path to site assets]/SiteAssets/newform.aspx`.Go to the where you stored the script and copy the link displayed by the browser: copy until `/SiteAssets/` or `/[library internal name]/` for another library. Then append the scrpt name. You can notice that the relative URL is sufficient and it starts at `/sites/`.
However the `newform.aspx` has to be edited this way:

```
        <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
            <SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="sp.ribbon.js" runat="server" OnDemand="true" Localizable="false" />
            <SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="SP.js" runat="server" OnDemand="true" Localizable="false" />

            <script type="text/javascript">
                /*Your script here*/
                /*examples*/
                myFunction1()
                {}
                myFunction2()
                {}
                 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) 
                 {                           
                        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myFunction1, "sp.js");          //if the function operates on the form
                        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myFunction2, "sp.ribbon.js");   //if the function operates on the ribbon
                });

            </script> 

            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
             <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                    <head>
                        <meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
                        <title>Page</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>

                    </body>

            </html>

    </asp:Content>
```

1. Ask the server to load `sp.js and sp.ribbon.js` by adding the necessary tags at the top of the page if you want to work on the form and/or the ribbon
2. You can add custom html : remove otherwise
3. Save as `.aspx`

Comment: i was able to add the URL under content link.

Do i need to add the webpart in header or body section?

 how can i edit the newform.aspx?

Comment: @saeid10 When you click on `Default New Form` you can see `Add a Web Part` inside a box. Click on it.

Comment: thanks I got it done. 
but i used the html code which was on the site

Answer (score 1):

**Steps:**

- Download [SPUtility.js](https://sputility.codeplex.com/).
- Upload the downloaded file (SPUtility.js) to an appropriate place in SharePoint Site like ‘Style Library’.
- Open your list > From the above ribbon, > In ‘Customize List‘ Section > Click on ‘Form Web Parts‘ > Select ‘Default New Form‘.
- Add Script Editor in your New form.
- Edit Snippet > Add the below code.

**Code**

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () 
{ // Get a the choice field 
var choiceField = SPUtility.GetSPField('Job Title');
// Hide the target fields in form load
SPUtility.GetSPField('Other Title').Hide();
// create a function to show or hide a field based on the selected choice Field value 
var ShowHideField = function() { 
var selectedFieldValue = choiceField.GetValue(); 
// Hide the 'Other Title' field if the selected value is 'Other' 
if(selectedFieldValue != 'Other') { 
SPUtility.GetSPField('Other Title').Hide(); } 
else { SPUtility.GetSPField('Other Title').Show(); } }; 
// attach the function to choice field 
$(choiceField.Dropdown).on('change', ShowHideField); });
</script>
```

**[OutPut]**

[image: https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/show-hide-fields-based-on-a-drop-down-using-sputility-js/]

[image: https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/show-hide-fields-based-on-choice-field-selection-using-jquery-in-sharepoint/]

> **Note:** Replace the `Job Title` with your choice field name and `Other Title` with your field that you need to show or hide based on
>   the choice field selection.

**For more details, Please check**

- For Edit / Display form **[Show / Hide fields based on a drop-down field using SPUtility.js](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/show-hide-fields-based-on-a-drop-down-using-sputility-js/)**
- **[Show / Hide fields based on choice field selection using JQuery in SharePoint](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/show-hide-fields-based-on-choice-field-selection-using-jquery-in-sharepoint/)**